# how to save duplicate code on multiple similar Dockerfiles

Tags: docker

I didn't see a valid answer for this. 
I have a Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:screencast' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin without-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

It's the same docker file duplicated in all of my 10 services. How can I "import" the Dockerfile code lines from a shared location to solve duplicate code?

Follow up question is what to do if I have slightly changed `Dockerfile` in all of my services?

Comment: You can build it and push it to your locally hosted (or even public) Docker Registry and then just pull it whenever you need it. If I understand you right OFC.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I don't want to manage a remote docker registry. just import docker lines from one file to another

Comment: As I wrote pushing it to the public registry at https://hub.docker.com is also an option

Comment: but's it's private.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand you... What's private?

Comment: The dockerfile's content.

Comment: There's nothing in it that I'd consider super secret. I don't see a reason to keep it private.

Comment: Answer to the other question `what to do if I have slightly changed Dockerfile in all of my services` highly depends on what these 'slight changes' actually are. YOu'd need to be more specific about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance is not possible at a Dockerfile level. 
You will have to create a base Docker image which will include all the common steps. Then the application docker files will use the base Docker image.